# Faster API access via javascript or server-side libraries

Tags: performance, api

I would like to display information obtained from a web-API.  (say, instagram or last.fm)

Is there generally a noticable speed difference between using a serverside (Ruby) or clientside (JS) API library?

I would guess Javascript would be faster since you can contact the API asynchronously once the page has loaded in the client's browser

Just wondering if there is a "best practice" for this since API libraries generally exist for both client-side and server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each way has pro and cons, one really isn't better or worse than the other for a general case, you have to use what makes sense in your situation.

With a small amount of data / operations, you will most likely be throttled by the web request itself, not the processing power of either JavaScript or Ruby.

I haven't made an exhaustive list, but some general things to consider:

Client Side:

- Processing power is pushed over to the client, you use less resources, but performance will vary.
- API must support either JSONp or Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
- Very slow for large operations on large data sets.
- Any API key will be viewable by any visitor to your website.
- Initial response time from your server will be quicker, but if you load most of your content from an API request, you'll still have to wait.

Server Side:

- Won't expose an API key to the client.
- Uses more resources, but can handle larger amounts of data/operations
- Will take a longer amount of time to return the initial page.
- Sometimes has additional user features/methods since oAuth or other security features are supported.

Answer (score 1):

One big difference is that the JS API does not add load on your server, so it makes it easier to scale your web app.

Also, in general using JS is likely to be faster to the user because the client's browser will be getting the data directly from the web-API server, rather than going via your server.